Associated and Affiliated random vectors
I'm reading Weber and Milgrom 1981 paper. I meet the following question. They define the concept of associated and affiliated random variable in a general way (without assuming the existence of joint density). My question is:

Does Association imply Affiliation?
I'm not sure what's the meaning of conditional on a set. Can I safely take it like the formula of conditional probability $P(A|B)=P(AB)/P(B)$?
What's the meaning of conditional on a sub lattice?


I will attach their formal definition here:
First, a subset $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is called increasing if its indicator function $1_A$ is nondecreasing. Second, a subset $S$ of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is a sublattice if its indicator function $1_S$ is affiliated, i.e., if $z \vee z^{\prime}$ and $z \wedge z^{\prime}$ are in $S$ whenever $z$ and $z^{\prime}$ are.
Let $Z=\left(Z_1, \ldots, Z_k\right)$ be a random $k$-vector with probability distribution $P$. Thus, $P(A)=\operatorname{Prob}(Z$ $\in A)$. We denote the intersection of the sets $A$ and $B$ by $A B$ and the complement of $A$ by $\bar{A}$.
Definition: $Z_1, \ldots, Z_k$ are associated if for all increasing sets $A$ and $B, P(A B) \geq P(A) P(B)$.
Definition: $Z_1, \ldots, Z_k$ are affiliated if for all increasing sets $A$ and $B$ and every sublattice $S$, $P(A B \mid S) \geq P(A \mid S) P(B \mid S)$, i.e., if the variables are associated conditional on any sublattice.
